# Is there a way to print the contents added to a knapsack for this 0/1 Greedy algorithm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, knapsack-problem

My most recent lab assignment has me trying to implement a Greedy algorithm for the 0/1 Knapsack problem, and print out the contents of the knapsack along with the total value of the knapsack. So far, I was able to get it to output the total value of the knapsack without issue, but I'm having trouble with outputting what items went into the knapsack.

```
#class definitions for the greedy approach
class Item: 
    def __init__(self,weight,value):
        self.weight = weight
        self.value = value
        self.price_kg = value / weight
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Item(weight={self.weight}, value={self.value},v/w={self.price_kg})\n"

class Knapsack: 
    def __init__(self,max_weight,items):
        self.max_weight = max_weight
        self.items = items
        self.contents = list()

    def fillGreedy(self):
        self.items.sort(key=lambda x: x.price_kg, reverse=True)#sorts the items by weight/value
        for i in self.items:
            self.contents.append(i)#Tries putting the item in the bag
            if sum(i.weight for i in self.contents) > self.max_weight:
                self.contents.remove(i)#Removes the item it is too heavy for the bag
            elif sum(i.weight for i in self.contents) == self.max_weight:#finds an optimal configuration for the bag
                return sum(i.value for i in self.contents)
            
        return sum(i.value for i in self.contents)

#main method
max_weights = [10, 13, 15, 30, 30]
weights = [
    [4, 5, 7],
    [6, 5, 7, 3, 1],
    [2, 3, 5, 5, 3, 7],
    [10, 13, 17, 15],
    [5, 4, 7, 6, 3, 4, 2, 1, 7, 6]
]
values = [
    [2, 3, 4],
    [7, 3, 4, 4, 3],
    [3, 4, 10, 9, 6, 13],
    [21, 17, 30, 23],
    [3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 1, 4]
]

for i in range(len(max_weights)):
    items = list()
    for j in range(len(weights[i])):
        items.append(Item(weights[i][j], values[i][j])) #adds the contents of the arrays to the Items list
 i
    ks = Knapsack(max_weights[i], items)
    v1 = ks.fillGreedy()
    print(f"Total value = {v1}")
    #print(items)
```

So far, I tried printing out the contents of the ks and v1 objects, but that only gives the memory addresses of the objects. I tried printing out the 'items' list itself after iterating through the fillGreedy method, but it prints out all the contents of the list and not the ones in the knapsack itself. I also tried doing something in the fillGreedy method that would print the item that was just added, but it ended up causing conflicts. I'm unsure where to continue from here. Is there a way to print out the items of the knapsack using this approach?

Comment: You seem to have posted more code than what would be reasonable for your issue. Please read [ask] and how to make a [mre]; providing a MRE helps users answer your question and future users relate to your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the site.

You already have a collection of the selected items inside the Knapsack object, so you could iterate over ks.contents and print out the contents or whatever is needed from there...

```
for item in ks.contents:
    print(item)
```

Comment: sure.  If the question is answered, you should "accept" the answer by hitting the check mark above to close it out.  Good luck w/ the class!